# How to extract open graph meta data from a webpage using UIPath RPA?

Tags: meta-tags, rpa, facebook-opengraph, uipath

Learning RPA with UIPath.  Happily extracting onscreen data from a website, processing it, using it, etc.

However, there's information in the page that isn't visible, but is in the source, eg, open graph meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/foo.jpg" />
```

What options are open to me to extract this with UIPath?  I gather there's an ExtractMetaData flag from ExtractData but  I've yet to find a useful tutorial that I can follow at this stage :/

Comment: You can use UI Explorer to get the selectors for meta tag you are interested in and then use the GetAttribure activity to get the content of a tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can try and use **Data Scraping** option by selecting the respected option from the **Wizards Tab** as show below:

[image]

Now you need to indicate on the screen the area of data that you need to scrape, like:

1. Structure data in form of table
2. Specific element on the web page
3. Or the whole window

**Data scraping activity** generates a container (**Attach Browser or Attach Window**) with a **selector** for the top-level window and an **Extract Structured Data activity** with a **partial selector** as per images below:

[image] 
[image]

So all you need to do is place your **XML tag** as Input under **ExtractMetadata field** as per image below:

[image]

Hope these information will be useful.

Comment: Thanks! I've used DataScraping but wasn't sure how to select the non-visible stuff.  I presume this means I just use the input as "<meta property="og:image"..."?  Heading off to try it this morning.

Comment: Hmm.  Trying with:  <extract>
 <column exact='1' name='Content' attr='content'>
  <webctrl tag='meta' property='og:image'/>
 </column>
</extract>
but it's just returning blank :/ Any thoughts?

Comment: try spying the whole window where your metadata exists and then place your value <meta property="og:image" content=.../> in ExtractMetadata field.